# How exactly do you use variables in Jenkins?

Tags: variables, jenkins

Can someone concisely explain what the differences between the three variables below are? Because in all honesty, when I create a Jenkins job, I randomly guess between the three types until something works, but I'd love to understand rather than blindly picking.

```
${ENV,var="BUILD_USER"}
${BUILD_USER}
$BUILD_USER
```

Also, are there other ways of writing variables in Jenkins that I missed other than the 3 ways above?

Comment: In which context do you use the variables? In a build step? In Unix shell? Or windows CMD?

Comment: I don't mean just the build step, although that is certainly included. I mean anywhere in the configuration page of a Jenkins job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, variable expansion is up to the plugin that interprets a configuration value.

For example, if you set up a job parameter GIT_REPOSITORY and use it to configure an address where git clone should go by putting $GIT_REPOSITORY into the git repository field, it works, but only because the Jenkins git plugin has implemented variable expansion support.

Many plugins do implement it but you cannot know it unless you test it. However, these days the support is so common it is safe to assume it should work.

Both forms of reference, $VAR and ${VAR}, work and are equivalent. The latter form is useful if you need to use the variable in a place where it is surrounded by other characters that could be interpreted as part of variable, like $VARX (Jenkins would be looking for variable named VARX) and ${VAR}X (Jenkins understands the variable is named VAR).

These rules have been modeled after variable expansion rules in Unix shells. Indeed, the job variables are made available as environment variables to build steps and in the Unix shell build step the variables are used the same way as above.

In a Windows CMD build step the variables are again used like any Windows environment variable: %VAR%.

Answer (score 1):

When used in a statement:
${ENV,var="BUILD_USER"}--evaluates the system environment variables and returns the value for the variable BUILD_USER.

example: curl ${ENV,var="BUILD_USER"}/api/xml

${BUILD_USER} --returns the value of the BUILD_USER variable in the current script memory space.

example: curl ${BUILD_USER}/api/xml

$BUILD_USER--used to assign values to the BUILD_USER variable.

example: $BUILD_USER = "BUILD_USER"

Comment: I believe these are not entirely correct, at least if we're talking about using the variables in a Unix shell build step.